# Why relationship that were set with Fluent API are being lost after restarting app?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have two classes:

```
class Owner
{
    [Key]
    public int OwnerID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public Owner()
    {
        Cars = new List<Car>();
    }
}

class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {
        Owners = new List<Owner>();
    }
}
```

I am setting many to many relationship in database context using Fluent API:

```
class CarsListDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public CarsListDataContext() : base("name=CarsListConnectionString")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
                    .HasMany(car => car.Owners)
                    .WithMany(owner => owner.Cars);
    }
}
```

And I run this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dbContext = new CarsListDataContext();

        var owner = new Owner()
        {
            Name = "John Smith"
        };

        var car = new Car()
        {
            Model = "Volkswagen Beetle"
        };

        owner.Cars.Add(car);
        car.Owners.Add(owner);

        dbContext.Owners.Add(owner);
        dbContext.Cars.Add(car);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        foreach (var o in dbContext.Owners)
        {
            string cars = string.Empty;
            foreach (var c in o.Cars)
            {
                cars += c.Model;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(o.Name + ": " + cars);
        }

        foreach (var c in dbContext.Cars)
        {
            string owners = string.Empty;
            foreach (var o in c.Owners)
            {
                owners += o.Name;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(c.Model + ": " + owners);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Everything is OK, Entity Framework creates new database and app's output looks like:

```
John Smith: Volkswagen Beetle
Volkswagen Beetle: John Smith
```

Then I remove lines which add new values to database:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dbContext = new CarsListDataContext();

    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    foreach (var o in dbContext.Owners)
    {
         string cars = string.Empty;
         foreach (var c in o.Cars)
         {
              cars += c.Model;
         }
         Console.WriteLine(o.Name + ": " + cars);
     }

     foreach (var c in dbContext.Cars)
     {
         string owners = string.Empty;
         foreach (var o in c.Owners)
         {
             owners += o.Name;
         }
         Console.WriteLine(c.Model + ": " + owners);
      }

      Console.ReadKey();
}
```

If I run this code, I get:

```
John Smith:
Volkswagen Beetle:
```

So why does the relationship between owners and cars is being lost? I am using SQL Server 2012 LocalDB, if it matters.

Comment: Likely because lazy loading is not enabled, and you are not `include()` the Owners.

Comment: Check if the entities are actually created in the database.

Comment: Possibly not relevant, but you've left the `dbContext.SaveChanges();` line in.

Comment: See [Eager Loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/eager-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx) and [Lazy Loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx).

Comment: Brendan Green, Ivan Stoev, thank you very much, I changed my code from 'foreach (var o in dbContext.Owners) {...}' to 'foreach (var o in dbContext.Owners.Include(o => o.Cars)) {...}' and now it works correctly. This problem was driving me crazy and thanks to you it was solved.